# How to get non-normalized feature importances with random forest in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm using the feature_importances_ attribute in the random forest classifier of scikit-learn to plot the importances of each feature. However, I'd like to plot these importances non-normalized. I have searched around how to do this, but there doesn't seem to be an easy method how to do this. I tried manually:

```
temp = [t.tree_.compute_feature_importances(normalize=True) for t in clf.estimators_]
arr = np.array(temp)
arr2=[]
for i in range(19):
    arr2.append(sum(arr[:,i]))
arr3 = np.array(arr2)
indices = np.argsort(arr3)[::-1]
indices.reshape(1,-1)

plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(X_train.shape[1]), arr3[indices],
        color="r", align="center")
plt.xticks(range(X_train.shape[1]), indices)
plt.xlim([-1, X_train.shape[1]])
plt.show()
```

Which gives these results for normalize=True and normalize=False respectively. (the normalize parameter seems to be inverted somehow...?)
[image: normalize=True]
[image: normalize=False]

For reference, this is the result from using feature_importances_ (the error-bars are not relevant to the question):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are normalizing the Gini dip for every tree and then summing those values.

 You should do the normalization at the end after the sum.

*Result might vary depending upon the overall numbers in the two scenarios.*

See this dummy example

```py
import numpy as np
# Three Tree and 3 Features. F1 sum across Trees = 50, F2 = 48, F3 = 20
gini_dip = np.array([[20, 15, 5], [20, 15, 5], [10, 18, 10]]) 

# Normaliation before sum
gini_dip_n = np.array([((elem-min(elem))/(max(elem)-min(elem))) for elem in gini_dip])
fi_1 = gini_dip_n.sum(axis=0)

# Normaliation After sum
gini_dip_sum = gini_dip.sum(axis=0)
fi_2 = (gini_dip_sum - gini_dip_sum.min())/(gini_dip_sum.max() - gini_dip_sum.min())

fi_1, fi_2
```

> *(array([2.        , 2.33333333, 0.        ]),
>
>  array([1.        , 0.93333333, 0.        ]))*

*F2 is best in scenario #1 and F1 is best in scenario #2*